# Obtain velocity from imposed energy spectrum using the inverse FFT

Tags: finite-volume, fourier-analysis, discontinuous-galerkin, fourier-transform

I am trying to obtain the spatial representation of $u(x)$ (e.g. velocity) from its energy spectrum $E(k)=k^4\exp(-(k/k_0)^2)$, which is given in the frequency domain, provided $|u(k)|=\sqrt{2E(k)}$. I need a real $u(x)$ to use it as initial condition for a simulation using FV.

How can I obtain a real $u(x)$ using the inverse FFT applied to $E(k)$?

I have seen that a phase perturbation is sometimes added as $|u(k)|=\sqrt{2E(k)}\exp(i2\pi p(k))$, where $p(k)$ is a random number that satisfies $p(k)=-p(-k)$. However, this does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you first read [answer here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/33460/28872) to find out why $\tilde{E}(\mathbf{k}) \neq \frac{1}{2} \tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{k}) \cdot \tilde{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{k})$. In order to find velocity profile from Fourier transform ($\mathscr{F}$) of kinetic energy ($E(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r})$), you could obtain it like this:

$$\mathscr{F} \{E(\mathbf{r}) \} = \tilde{E}(\mathbf{k}) = \int_{\Omega} E(\mathbf{r}) e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}} d^{3} \mathbf{r}$$

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1} \{ \tilde{E}(\mathbf{k}) \} = E(\mathbf{r}) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}})^{3} \int_{\Omega_{\mathbf{k}}} \tilde{E}(\mathbf{k}) e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} d^{3} \mathbf{k}$$

Where $E$ is kinetic energy and its Fourier transform is $\tilde{E}$, $\Omega$ is your computational domain and $\Omega_{\mathbf{k}}$ is the computational domain in Fourier space. Finally:

$$|\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r})| = \sqrt{2 \mathscr{F}^{-1} \{ \tilde{E} (\mathbf{k}) \}}$$

So, the procedure would be taking inverse Fourier transform ($\mathscr{F}^{-1}$) from $\tilde{E}$ and then calculate the magnitude of the velocity from it. But, you need to know that it just gives you the **magnitude** of the velocity and not full 3D vector of the velocity due to the fact that there is no unique inverse of dot product operator.

For your special case where the $\Omega$ is a 1D line and $E(k) = k^4 \exp(-(\frac{k}{k_{0}})^2)$:

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1} \{ E(k) \} = E(x) = \frac{k_{0}^{4} |k_{0}|}{16 \sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4} k_{0}^2 x^2} (k_{0}^4 x^4 - 12 k_{0}^2 x^2 + 12)$$

$$u(x) = \pm \sqrt{2 E(x)} = \pm \frac{k_{0}^{2}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{|k_{0}|}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{4} k_{0}^2 x^2} (k_{0}^4 x^4 - 12 k_{0}^2 x^2 + 12)}$$

Note that this solution is valid only for $0 < x < \frac{\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{2}}}{|k_{0}|}$ or $x > \frac{\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}}}{|k_{0}|}$ (I assumed your $x$ is positive!).

For $\frac{\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{2}}}{|k_{0}|} < x < \frac{\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{2}}}{|k_{0}|}$, you should take the real part of this expression as the solution:

$$u(x) = \pm \frac{k_{0}^{2}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{|k_{0}|}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{4} k_{0}^2 x^2}} \Re \Big\{ \sqrt{(k_{0}^4 x^4 - 12 k_{0}^2 x^2 + 12)} \Big\}$$

These two expressions are positive roots of the fourth-order polynomial in the inverse Fourier transform ($k_{0}^{4} x^{4} - 12k_{0}^{2} x^{2} + 12$). The plot of solution for variable $x$ and $k_{0}$ are shown here:

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed explanation!